# Iterator in permutation value order

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, permutation

I have a simple struct for permutation:

```
struct Permutation
{
   vector<string> items; // ["val_0", "val_1", "val_2", "val_3", "val_4"]
   vector<short> permutationValue;  // Let's say value is [4, 2, 0, 1, 3]
}
```

I want to be able to use it in range loop, like that

```
for(string item: permutation){
{ 
    cout << item << endl;
}
```

end expected output should be:

```
val_4
val_2
val_0
val_1
val_3
```

What methods should I implement in `Permutation` class to achive it?

Comment: begin(), end() which returns iterators

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski I assume that iterator should some kind special? Could you clarify it.

Comment: A ranged for requires `begin()` and `end()` members. You can have `vector<string>::iterator begin() { return items.begin(); }` and relatively the `end()` function. You should make sure `items` already contains the permuted values though. Doing the computations in the iterator implementation itself would be a pain.

Comment: @DeiDei unfortunately I can't go that way, because in real case elements is quite heavy, and permutation only contains link to single set of items, and this set shared across all permutations, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do a little bit of work. You need to implement your own custom iterator class, and `begin()` and `end()`:

```
struct Permutation
{
    std::vector<std::string> items;
    std::vector<short> permutationValue;

    class iterator;

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

};
```

Your iterator class will be a random access iterator:

```
#include <iterator>

class Permutation::iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, std::string>
{


};
```

It is important to inherit from `std::iterator`, in order for your custom iterator to work correctly with `<algorithm>`.

There are several possible ways to implement the iterator. But the general idea is that your iterator will store a pointer to its permutation object, and its current index position, in its private class members:

```
private:
    Permutation *p;
    size_t pos;
```

Its `operator*` is obvious:

```
public:
    std::string &operator*() const
    {
         return p->items[p->permutationValue[pos]];
    }
```

You will need to implement all other iterator operators, that increment/decrement advance the random access iterator, operators `++`, `--`, `+`, `-`, `+=`, `-=`, simply by adding or subtracting `pos`.

You will also need to implement all the comparison operators for your iterator class: `<`, `>`, `=`, `!=`, `<=`, and `>=`, simply by comparing `pos`.

These bits will be a little bit tedious, but inavoidable.

Now, all you have to do is implement `begin()` and `end()` by constructing this iterator instance, setting the initial `pos` to either 0, or `items.size();`. You're done. Now you can use range iteration.

For extra credit, you can also implement `const_iterator`.

In conclusion: it's going to be a little bit of work, but it's not very complicated.

Comment: "It is important to inherit from `std::iterator`" It's also important to not use a deprecated feature.

Comment: @T.C. Could you advice, what should be used as base type instead deprecated iterator?

Comment: The "long sequence of void declarations" that's cited as, supposedly, the sole justification for deprecating `std::iterator` is used in the least frequently used iterator implementations. I expect that this deprecation to be generally ignored. Sadly, on rare occasions, the established academia spends too much time entrenched in their ivory halls, and comes up with these kinds of whoppers. Feel free to add even more mind-numbing boilerplate to your iterators, just to be on the cutting edge of technology. I'll stick with `std::iterator`, thankyouverymuch.

Comment: It must be nice to make claims about "ivory halls" based on things you suppose, no? `std::iterator`'s issues isn't limited to clarity. Its name is misleading, and its usefulness is limited in generic code because it's usually a dependent base - which means you can't actually use the typedefs when writing the iterator itself.

Comment: Strange... I don't recall experiencing too much trouble writing `typedef std::iterator< ... > base_t;` then `typedef base_t::value_type value_type;`, etc... in the iterator itself, and using it. Besides, the iterator itself would know what it's `value_type` is, and just use it directly. Or use `auto`. Maybe I just got lucky...

Comment: Forgot the `typename`, didn't you? And what happened to boilerplate avoidance? Or DRY?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I was giving a formal code example, that was going to get graded by a professor. Furthermore a single typedef that aliases the base class, and gives access to all of the base class members, is orders of magnitude smaller than now having to spell out all those typedefs that `std::iterator` was defining for me. But, I guess that's progress: instead of a single typedef, defining half a dozen more. I must admit that that blurb in P0174, that lays out the argument, shares a lot in common with "Spaceballs". Every time I read/watch it, it gets funnier.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't complete code for forward/backward/random access iterators but it's a good place to start:

```
struct perm_iter {
  const vector<short>& perm_;
  const vector<string>& items_;
  int idx_ {0};
  perm_iter(int idx, const vector<short>& perm, const vector<string>& items)
    : idx_(idx)
    , perm_(perm)
    , items_(items) {}

  perm_iter& operator++() {
    idx_++;
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator!=(const perm_iter& i) const {
    return idx_ != i.idx_;
  }

  string operator*() {
    return items_[perm_[idx_]];
  }

};

struct Permutation
{
  /* ... */ 
   perm_iter begin() {
      return perm_iter(0, permutationValue, items);  
   }

   perm_iter end() {
      return perm_iter(items.size(), permutationValue, items);
   }

};

 //usage:
 Permutation p;
 for (string s : p)
    cout << s << endl;
```